# For the superposition state of a composite system, how to use the quantum amplitude amplification algorithm to simultaneously amplify several of them

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

For the superposition state $|\Phi \rangle =\frac{1}{16}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{15}{(|i\rangle |{{a}_{i}}\rangle )}$ (The second quantum system ${a}_{i}$ is not necessarily all orthogonal) of a composite system, how to use the quantum amplitude amplification algorithm to simultaneously  amplify several of them, such as $|3\rangle |{{a}_{3}}\rangle $, $|5\rangle |{{a}_{5}}\rangle $ and $|8\rangle |{{a}_{8}}\rangle $? If this is not feasible, is it possible to use other methods to filter out unwanted items?

Comment: Are the different $|a_i\rangle$ assumed orthogonal to each other?

Comment: The quantum states of the second system are not necessarily orthogonal, they may even be equal

Comment: Can the oracle for what should and shouldn't be amplified be determined based only on $|i\rangle$ values, and do we have access to the unitary to create this superposition?

Comment: Sorry, I have little research on the oracle algorithm and don't know how to construct it, another question is, is it more difficult to construct the oracle assuming that the states I need are random rather than specified?

Comment: In fact, I prefer to explain this problem through quantum gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume a unitary $U$ such that $U |0\rangle^{\otimes(n+4)} = |\Phi \rangle \equiv \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i = 0}^{15} (|i \rangle |a_i \rangle)$ is given, where $\{|a_i \rangle\}_{i=0}^{15}$ are all $n$-qubit states. For the sake of concreteness, let us consider the particular example you mentioned, i.e., that the states to amplify are $\{|3\rangle |a_3\rangle, |5\rangle |a_5\rangle, |8\rangle |a_8\rangle\}$. In such case we can split the input state $|\Phi \rangle$ as

$|\Phi\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} |\Phi_{target}\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{13}}{4} |\Phi_{discarded}\rangle,$

where $|\Phi_{target}\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|3\rangle |a_3\rangle + |5\rangle |a_5\rangle + |8\rangle |a_8\rangle)$. The diffusion operator is implemented as

[image]

where the $Z$ gate acting on the ancilla prepared in state $|1\rangle$ is only triggered if all $n+4$ qubits in the main register are in state $|0\rangle$. The oracle must apply a phase shift of $e^{i \pi} = -1$ only to $|\Phi_{target}\rangle$ and not to $|\Phi_{discarded}\rangle$. Perhaps the simplest implementation of this oracle corresponds to applying the phase shift to each term separately. For the particular case considered here, the oracle is implemented as follows.

[image]

Putting the pieces together, the full quantum amplitude amplification circuit looks like this.

[image]

The subcircuit inside the curved brackets is repeated $M$ times. For $M = 0$, such subcircuit is not executed at all, in which case we merely prepare $|\Phi \rangle$ and the weight carried by the desired part $|\Phi_{target} \rangle$ is $p = \frac{3}{16} = 18.75 \%$. Every repetition of the subcircuit rotates the state in the relevant two-dimensional subspace $\{ |\Phi_{target}\rangle, |\Phi_{discarded}\rangle \}$ by $\theta = \arctan(\frac{2\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{1-2p}) \approx 51^{\circ}$. The initial state is at an angle $\theta_0 = \arcsin(\sqrt{p}) \approx 26^{\circ}$ from the x-axis defined by $|\Phi_{discarded}\rangle$, so for $M=1$ the angle relative to the x-axis becomes $26^{\circ} + 51^{\circ} = 77^{\circ}$ and the weight carried by the target state is amplified to $\sin^{2}(77^{\circ}) \approx 95\%$. A second execution of the subcircuit (i.e., $M = 2$) will no longer produce an improvement; the weight of the desired part will fall to $\approx 62\%$. This is a manifestation of the so-called *[soufflé problem](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.275.5300.627)*: Iterating too few times "undercooks" the state, but iterating too many "overcooks" it.

If we wish to increase the weight of the desired part arbitrarily close to $100 \%$, we can make use of a so-called fixed-point amplitude amplification method, which addresses the soufflé problem, in that the more iterations we execute, the greater the weight of the desired part is. The [original fixed-point method](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.95.150501), the so-called phase-$\frac{\pi}{3} method$, was devised by Lov Grover and corresponds to a clever recursive adaptation of his original algorithm. The [state-of-the-art fixed point method](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.210501) was proposed by Yoder, Low and Chuang and addresses the soufflé problem whilst also retaining the quadratic speed-up of the Grover algorithm.